# Create spherical voids in a cube with having the coordinates of center of all spheres in python to run in Abaqus

Tags: python, coordinates, abaqus

I'm writing a script to run in Abaqus. 
I want to create a cube (1*1*1). Then I want to create 63 voids in the cube.
I have the center coordinates of all spheres and also the radius. both in csv file and in python code.
I have problem with defining the coordinates. I wanna create a porous solid.
Here is my code.
Can you help me? Thank you so much.

```
# -*- coding: mbcs -*-
from part import *
from material import *
from section import *
from assembly import *
from step import *
from interaction import *
from load import *
from mesh import *
from optimization import *
from job import *
from sketch import *
from visualization import *
from connectorBehavior import *
import numpy as np
from coordinates import Coordinate.from_sequence *


############################################
# defining data (Units: meter and Newton)

L = 1 # lengh of cube 
cricle_radius = 0.1407
ball = 63
num_ball = 63# max ball
############################################

mdb.models['Model-1'].ConstrainedSketch(name='__profile__', sheetSize=0.5)
mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].rectangle(point1=(0.0, 0.0), 
    point2=(0.04, 0.05))
mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].ObliqueDimension(textPoint=(
    -0.0247507989406586, 0.0196989551186562), value=L, vertex1=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].vertices[0], vertex2=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].vertices[1])
mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].ObliqueDimension(textPoint=(
    0.0256675183773041, 0.0636780187487602), value=L, vertex1=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].vertices[1], vertex2=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].vertices[2])
mdb.models['Model-1'].Part(dimensionality=THREE_D, name='Part-1', type=
    DEFORMABLE_BODY)
mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1'].BaseSolidExtrude(depth=L, sketch=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'])
del mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__']

mdb.models['Model-1'].ConstrainedSketch(name='__profile__', sheetSize=0.5)
mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].ConstructionLine(point1=(0.0, 
    -0.25), point2=(0.0, 0.25))
mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].FixedConstraint(entity=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].geometry[2])
mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].ArcByCenterEnds(center=(0.0, 0.0)
    , direction=COUNTERCLOCKWISE, point1=(0.0, -0.04), point2=(0.0, 0.04))
mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].CoincidentConstraint(
    addUndoState=False, entity1=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].vertices[2], entity2=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].geometry[2])
mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].CoincidentConstraint(
    addUndoState=False, entity1=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].vertices[0], entity2=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].geometry[2])
mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].CoincidentConstraint(
    addUndoState=False, entity1=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].vertices[1], entity2=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].geometry[2])
mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].RadialDimension(curve=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].geometry[3], radius= cricle_radius, 
    textPoint=(0.0178755968809128, 0.0190117806196213))
mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].Line(point1=(0.0, cricle_radius), point2=(
    0.0, -cricle_radius))
mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].VerticalConstraint(addUndoState=
    False, entity=mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].geometry[4])
mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].PerpendicularConstraint(
    addUndoState=False, entity1=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].geometry[3], entity2=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'].geometry[4])
mdb.models['Model-1'].Part(dimensionality=THREE_D, name='sphere', type=
    DEFORMABLE_BODY)
mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['sphere'].BaseSolidRevolve(angle=360.0, 
    flipRevolveDirection=OFF, sketch=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__'])
del mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__']

mdb.models['Model-1'].Material(name='Material-1')
mdb.models['Model-1'].materials['Material-1'].Elastic(table=((200000000000.0, 
    0.3), ))
mdb.models['Model-1'].HomogeneousSolidSection(material='Material-1', name=
    'Section-1', thickness=None)
mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1'].Set(cells=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1'].cells.getSequenceFromMask(('[#1 ]', 
    ), ), name='Set-1')
mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1'].SectionAssignment(offset=0.0, 
    offsetField='', offsetType=MIDDLE_SURFACE, region=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1'].sets['Set-1'], sectionName=
    'Section-1', thicknessAssignment=FROM_SECTION)
mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.DatumCsysByDefault(CARTESIAN)
mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.Instance(dependent=ON, name='Part-1-1', 
    part=mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1'])
mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.translate(instanceList=('Part-1-1', ), 
    vector=(0.0, 0.15, 0.0))
mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.translate(instanceList=('Part-1-1', ), 
    vector=(0.0, 0.8, 0.0))



######################################################
###############  Algorithm  #########################

coords = Coordinate.from_sequence([Coordinates of centers like (x,y,z) should be write here], order='xyz')
coords = np.resize(coords,(63,3))    

######################################################


for x in range(1,ball): 

    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.Instance(dependent=ON, name='sphere-'+str(x), 
        part=mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['sphere'])
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-'+str(x)].translate(vector=(
        0, 0.0, 0.0))
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.translate(instanceList=('sphere-'+str(x), ), 
        vector=(coords[x][0], coords[x][1], coords[x][2]))




mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.InstanceFromBooleanCut(cuttingInstances=(
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-1'], 
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-2'], 
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-3'], 
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-4'], 
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-5'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-6'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-7'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-8'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-9'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-10'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-11'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-12'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-13'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-14'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-15'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-16'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-17'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-18'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-19'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-20'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-21'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-22'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-23'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-24'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-25'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-26'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-27'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-28'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-29'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-30'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-31'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-32'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-33'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-34'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-35'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-36'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-37'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-38'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-39'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-40'], 
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-41'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-42'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-43'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-44'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-45'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-46'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-47'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-48'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-49'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-50'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-51'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-52'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-53'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-54'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-55'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-56'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-57'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-58'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-59'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-60'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-61'],
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['sphere-62']),
    instanceToBeCut=mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['Part-1-1'], name='Part-2', 
    originalInstances=DELETE)       



mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-2'].setMeshControls(elemShape=TET, regions=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-2'].cells.getSequenceFromMask(('[#1 ]', 
    ), ), technique=FREE)
mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-2'].setElementType(elemTypes=(ElemType(
    elemCode=C3D20R, elemLibrary=STANDARD), ElemType(elemCode=C3D15, 
    elemLibrary=STANDARD), ElemType(elemCode=C3D10, elemLibrary=STANDARD)), 
    regions=(mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-2'].cells.getSequenceFromMask((
    '[#1 ]', ), ), ))
mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-2'].seedPart(deviationFactor=0.1, 
    minSizeFactor=0.1, size=0.1)
mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-2'].generateMesh()
mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.regenerate()
mdb.models['Model-1'].StaticStep(initialInc=0.2, name='Step-1', previous=
    'Initial')

mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.Set(faces=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['Part-2-1'].faces.getSequenceFromMask(
    ('[#8 ]', ), ), name='Set-1')
mdb.models['Model-1'].EncastreBC(createStepName='Step-1', localCsys=None, name=
    'BC-1', region=mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.sets['Set-1'])
mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.Surface(name='Surf-1', side1Faces=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['Part-2-1'].faces.getSequenceFromMask(
    ('[#2 ]', ), ))
mdb.models['Model-1'].Pressure(amplitude=UNSET, createStepName='Step-1', 
    distributionType=UNIFORM, field='', magnitude=10000.0, name='Load-1', 
    region=mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.surfaces['Surf-1'])
```

Comment: Be more precise in defining your problem. i.e. Are you having problems in a specific portion of your code? This is not a code writing service.